# Menu does not showup first time after install

Tags: android, menu

i a facing very weird problem in my app. i am inflating a layout on pressing menu key. and setting that layout on popupwindow. the prob i am facing is that when i install build on device and press menu key, popup does not show up. but if i navigate to some other screen and come back to previous screen, menu key works perfectly.
even if i cllose app and open it next time, menu key works fine. it does not work for the first time after install.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set your click listener for the menu button in the wrong lifecycle method? Perhaps it doesn't add the listener until after onPause()? Seeing some source would be very helpful to be sure.

Comment: If you close the app, it would have called onPause then onStop then onDestroy. Just post some related code and maybe we can find exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think android pretty much decides on its own when it updates its layouts and redraws the view. Maybe your newly inflated view doesnt affect the other layouts in a way that makes this seem neccessary. I would try to call requestLayout()/forceLayout() on the main layout...
Not sure though...